# VSCode Python package inspection failure

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This's probably quite off-topic but maybe someone else share my experience... when I started coding **KiCAD** plugins and learning **Python** I decided to use **VSCode** (with Microsoft Python extension) because I already use it for a number of other things and works great.

I have two main issues mostly bound to **Python** extension itself other than **VSCode**:

1. VSCode try to use python 3.7 binary (I installed it on my
   machine and I need it) instead kicad/python 2 (it's installed on a different location);
2. even if I setup **VSCode** to look for additional packages with a specific configuration file (`settings.json`):

   ```
   "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:/Program Files/KiCad/lib/python2.7/site-packages"]
   ```

**VSCode** refuse to investigate `pcbnew.py` (located in that folder) and thus every Intellisense like function (inspection etc) doesn't work.

How can I fix that? ... I'm more interested in fixing the second issue other than the first.

Comment: Did you change your `"python.pythonPath"` to point to the appropriate interpreter? And when you say "VSCode refuses to investigate", what do you mean by that. No IntelliSense (and if so are you using Jedi or the Microsoft language server)? Won't debug into the file?

Comment: Yes I changed `python.pythonPath` as long as the path for extra packages but as far as I can see VSCode keeps using 3.7 python binary version and doesn't find extra packages... pretty strange. With _VSCode refuses to investigate_ I mean that the package inspector is not working and so I got no autocompletition, linting etc... Microsoft Python use *MS Language Server* of course..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "as long as the path for extra packages". What does the status bar say is the Python version?

As for "Microsoft Python use MS Language Server of course", it's actually not obvious as you must opt into using the language server or be in an experiment group. Try setting `"python.jediEnabled"` to both `true` and `false` and see if either value solves the problem.

Comment: @BrettCannon the path for extra packages is specified trough: `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`. In my specific case it gets the value I pasted in point 2 of the question above that's where the package I need python plugin to check for package elements (I hope). I assumed _MS Language Server_ was the default mechanism used by _MS Python Plugin_ (as a matter of fact I neither set it nor Intellisense)

Comment: the key issue is problem 1 where you're saying the wrong interpreter is selected. What interpreter is listed in the status bar and what is `"python.pythonPath"` set to in your `settings.json`?

Comment: I just fixed this by setting it trough VSCode's `settings` menu. In this way it seems to work. The problem is how to use this configuration just for **this** project and not for _every_ project. I tought I need to create a `.vscode` folder inside project one and to put there a local `settings.json` file but it's not working.

Comment: Yes, you can create a `.vscode/settings.json` file and put your settings there. If you are using the GUI editor for settings then you need to make sure to use the "Workspace" tab.

Comment: Yes !!! It works now... I cannot understand what I changed from my first unsuccesful trial but now specifying `python.pythonPath` in `.vscode/settings.json` works and packages are correctly inspected as I guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly enable *per project* configuration of **VSCode** / **Python** open folder and create a workspace configuration for the project itself (i.e. create a `.vscode` folder inside project folder and store a `settings.json` file inside it with you custom configuration). In my specific case I needed to specifiy a custom location for an older **Python** binary trough `python.pythonPath` directive.